# use git commands in script file

Tags: git, wsh

how to provide credentials while running Git commands through script file. as when i ran the git clone command on git bash it was asking me for username and password.

```
Set WinScriptHost = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set wshSystemEnv = WinScriptHost.Environment( "Process" )
wshSystemEnv("VALUE") = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\"

WinScriptHost.CurrentDirectory = "E:\BitBucket\lpawarRepo"
Return = WinScriptHost.Run("git.exe add .", 0, true)

'Wscript.Echo "Checking out from git 1.."

Return = WinScriptHost.Run("git.exe clone -b Test-UNIFY-4-3-0-BRANCH https://gitlab.com:esom-enterprise/esom-enterprise-platform.git", 0, true)

Set WinScriptHost = Nothing
```

Comment: Are you sure you meant to add the bash tag?  That looks more like wsh or VB script or something like that.  Perhaps those tags would be helpful for getting the right audience for your question

Comment: I would say, do `git` processing over `ssh` (with keypairs) instead of `https?`. It's in general safer and does not require credentials to be given (directly) in a terminal. After all it is possible a hacker listens to a terminal.

Comment: That's probably a bad idea to use credentials in script file (for security reasons). You can set up authentication over ssh or using windows credentials for user under which you run your script file.